# Help to (a) reinstall the OSCAR application & (b) verify the FILES directory tree

Tags: software-installation, files

I have had to erase my hard drive & would like some help to (1) reinstall the OSCAR application & (2) verify orphaned files in my new directory tree can be identified & deleted.

**Problem 1**: I do not know how to find OSCAR in the default software app. I think I found it here last year:
     http://www.apneaboard.com/wiki/index.php?title=OSCAR_Installation:_Linux
After restoring files from a remote storage using Deja dup backup tool I found this in my Downloads:
    oscar_1.0.1-r1_Ubuntu_amd64.deb /home/den/Downloads
I am reluctant to mess with the repository setup without help having tried that previously.

**Problem 2**: While the reformatting of the hard drive removed OSCAR, the restoration of files has returned these:
      OSCAR.desktop /home/den/Desktop
      OSCAR_Data /home/den/Documents/HEALTH

For other reasons I have changed the directory tree after restoring the backed-up files. So it will help me to know if this is the correct sequence....../home/whoamI/Documents or is it /whoamI/home/Documents? (And more broadly,I suspect apps like Firefox & Thunderbird will write their hidden files somewhere that can cause conflict with the restored hidden files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For OSCAR installation you can use its deb-package from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=oscar):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install oscar
```

And then execute `OSCAR` in the terminal to use it.

Comment: This solution may not have fixed the problem. I was expecting to see oscar in my list of installed programs.

Comment: den@den-K52JT:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
den@den-K52JT:~$ 

den@den-K52JT:~$ sudo apt-get install oscar
[sudo] password for den: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oscar is already the newest version (1.1.0-testing-3-3build1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
den@den-K52JT:~$...............Something might be stopping the installation?

Comment: It means that it is already installed. Run `OSCAR` from terminal to use it. I do not really know how it should work, but from packaging point of view it is installed and should work.

Comment: Thank you. You were correct. The program was accessible via the Terminal & it did run & I have tested it. I am very happy with that solution. Would you like to have a go at the second part of my problem?

Comment: The home folder is declared in $HOME variable (for *user* it means */home/user*) or `/home/$(whoami)/` path. So you have to place the backups here.

Comment: This was very helpful for a Newb like me, thanks for assisting me.

Comment: Nice to hear, so you can accept this answer by clicking on checkmark near it (in the left).